# Import Modules | Netmiko

Tags: import, module

I am new to programming and am trying to get figure out how to use modules in Python. Specifically, I am trying to install netmiko for network programmability. However it doesn't seem to be working.

I am using OSX High-Sierra and installed netmiko using `pip install netmiko`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: netmiko in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko>=2.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from netmiko) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scp>=0.10.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from netmiko) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from netmiko) (4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from netmiko) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: textfsm in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from netmiko) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (1.0.22)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko>=2.0.0->netmiko) (2.18)
```

It seems to have installed, but when I try using it in IDLE it doesn't seem to recognize it.

> >>> import Netmiko Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in 
>       import Netmiko ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Netmiko'

What am I doing wrong? I see that it doesn't recognize the module, but how to I get it to work?

Comment: Python is case sensitive, so `Netmiko` is not the same as `netmiko`. Use `import netmiko` and things should start to work. PS: please edit your post to properly format the screen output and error message.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek is correct; I just tried this on OSX Yosemite and it's case-sensitive. Use lowercase netmiko.

Comment: The same thing happened.

Comment: >>> import netmiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import netmiko
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netmiko'
>>>

Comment: Okay, I think that I have made some progress. I installed a newer version of pip by following this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBdZZGPpYxg

Comment: I can import netmiko in the default terminal, but IDLE still does not recognize the module.

Comment: I guess some environment variables or some scripts in your current working directory. Try to read this https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: you should type : pip3 install netmiko

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you must import Netmiko whith a uppercase N, from the libery netmiko (with lowercase N):

from netmiko import Netmiko

Here is an example on how to do some show commandos on a cisco switch with Netmiko:

https://github.com/aboyum/Netmiko-showcommand/blob/master/netmiko.py